# When user navigates to a page, is there an event other than Application_BeginRequest (in Global.asax)?

Tags: asp.net

I would like to log some data when a visitor navigates to a page. Thus, instead of the website log, there would be also a log for every single page. I couldn't find a way (except doing it in every single page, which is exhausting) to do so. Is there an event or any other method to do it without writing code to every single page's code behind?

I have tried Application_BeginRequest event, but it fires 2 times for every page. I don't know why it fires the second time when a user navigates to a page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write you code in a Master Page and it will ran for every page.
Probably your pages sent requests for some other resources, that's why you see two BeginRequests per page.

Comment: Thank you very much. I didn't know that the code behind is also shared among those child pages. Works perfect.